# Postgresql cannot restart No PostgreSQL clusters exist

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I want to restart my postgres using command

```
sudo service postgresql restart
```

However I'm getting the following error:

> [warn] No PostgreSQL clusters exist; see "man pg_createcluster" ...
> (warning).

I already have postgres running, showing through ps aux:

```
# ps aux| grep postgres
postgres     1  0.0  1.1 287484 24328 ?        Ss   21:58   0:00 postgres
postgres    77  0.0  0.4 287608  8588 ?        Ss   21:58   0:00 postgres: checkpointer process   
postgres    78  0.0  0.1 287484  3884 ?        Ss   21:58   0:00 postgres: writer process   
postgres    79  0.0  0.4 287484  8680 ?        Ss   21:58   0:00 postgres: wal writer process   
postgres    80  0.0  0.3 287896  6640 ?        Ss   21:58   0:00 postgres: autovacuum launcher process   
postgres    81  0.0  0.1 142612  3120 ?        Ss   21:58   0:00 postgres: stats collector process   
root      1253  0.0  0.0  12788   972 pts/0    S+   22:31   0:00 grep postgres
```

Now searching online, I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48552861/postgresql-no-postgresql-clusters-exist-see-man-pg-createcluster-during-ser). I followed the solution to create a cluster:

```
sudo pg_createcluster 9.6 main
sudo service postgresql stop
sudo service postgresql start
```

After this, I am able to "restart" posgres through

```
sudo service postgresql restart
```

HOWEVER, this is not on the original cluster. As if I run `ps-aux`, I see a new cluster setup, this is not what I want.

```
# ps aux| grep postgres
postgres     1  0.0  1.1 287484 24328 ?        Ss   21:58   0:00 postgres
postgres    77  0.0  0.4 287608  8588 ?        Ss   21:58   0:00 postgres: checkpointer process   
postgres    78  0.0  0.1 287484  3884 ?        Ss   21:58   0:00 postgres: writer process   
postgres    79  0.0  0.4 287484  8680 ?        Ss   21:58   0:00 postgres: wal writer process   
postgres    80  0.0  0.3 287896  6640 ?        Ss   21:58   0:00 postgres: autovacuum launcher process   
postgres    81  0.0  0.1 142612  3120 ?        Ss   21:58   0:00 postgres: stats collector process   
postgres  1292  0.0  1.2 287628 25680 ?        S    22:42   0:00 /usr/lib/postgresql/9.6/bin/postgres -D /var/lib/postgresql/9.6/main -c config_file=/etc/postgresql/9.6/main/postgresql.conf
postgres  1294  0.0  0.1 287628  3944 ?        Ss   22:42   0:00 postgres: 9.6/main: checkpointer process   
postgres  1295  0.0  0.1 287628  3940 ?        Ss   22:42   0:00 postgres: 9.6/main: writer process   
postgres  1296  0.0  0.1 287628  3944 ?        Ss   22:42   0:00 postgres: 9.6/main: wal writer process   
postgres  1297  0.0  0.3 288056  6464 ?        Ss   22:42   0:00 postgres: 9.6/main: autovacuum launcher process   
postgres  1298  0.0  0.1 142620  3172 ?        Ss   22:42   0:00 postgres: 9.6/main: stats collector process   
root      1329  0.0  0.0  12788   968 pts/0    S+   22:42   0:00 grep postgres
```

All the start/restart/stop is all applied to the new cluster. I just want to restart the original cluster. How can I do that?

Comment: It indicates that the original Postgres instance that is running `postgres` was created/started from a different system. What OS and version? Have you installed Postgres from more then one source? Have you looked in ``\etc\init.d\`` for a Postgres script? Add answers as update to your question.

Comment: PostgreSQL 9.6 EOL'd last month. Upgrade your system as soon as possible

Answer (score 0):

I found that this happened because the postgresql db was running inside a container. To restart the database, I'll need to restart the docker container